# How to validate HTML pages with R?

Tags: html, r, validation, rcurl

I have a list of URLs (large enough) and I want to check whether their HTML code is valid. If it is not, I want to know the number of errors and warnings like the results of this page: http://validator.w3.org/

Therefore, via R I want to submit my URLs to that webpage and then parse the results to get the information I need. Is there another way of doing it?

I've found the RCurl package but I'm not really sure how to go for it. I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I tried the following code which seems to kind of do the job although I still cannot process some URLs for some unknown reason for which I get an error and the code stops (therefore I lose everything).

```
HTMLValid=foreach(i=1:nrow(allData), .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
  library(RCurl)
  library(XML)
  url=paste("http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=",
            as.character(allData$url[i]),
            "&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0#preparse_warnings",
            sep="")
  w = getURL(url,httpheader = c('User-Agent' = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"))


  doc <- htmlTreeParse(w, getDTD = F)
  r=xmlRoot(doc)
  text=r[["body"]][[2]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
  errors=strsplit(toString.XMLNode(text),' ')[[1]][1]
  warnings=strsplit(toString.XMLNode(text),' ')[[1]][3]

  c(as.numeric(errors),as.numeric(warnings))
}
```

Probably I get errors when the page doesn't respond within a specific timeframe. How can I overcome this? Is there a way to do the procedure faster?

Comment: You might try `xmlSchemaValidate` from `library(XML)`.

Comment: You can specify the foreach `.errorhandling='remove'` option in order to filter out errors and only return the task results that succeeded.  In that way, you avoid losing everything when a few tasks fail.

Comment: @SteveWeston This way I won't be able to identify the cases for which I didn't get the results. Or maybe I could append the iterator in the results!!

Thomas I'll give it a try! Thanks!!

Comment: @Thomas I can't make it work for HTML files that are already saved on my pc. Do you have any working code?

Comment: I've never actually tried it for HTML (as opposed to other XML), so I don't have specific recommendations.

Comment: @Thomas A lot of valid HTML is invalid XML. My guess is that a schema validator copes very badly with that.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code.

You probably should not load your libraries inside your for loop. I'm not sure this would cause crashes but you should only load your libraries once.

More importantly, do not parallelise your web scraping. There are three reasons for this:
1) I do not see that you processing power will be the bottleneck here so you probably won't gain any performance by parallelising.
2) The errors might come from your making too frequent requests to the website and it "throws you out".
3) You are not collecting results as they come so that you lose all previously obtained results.

A simple fix: use a normal for loop, preferably with some timer inside to ensure you are not making too many requests per second. Save your results to a list at each step of the loop (incrementing your list's size).

If it still gets an error eventually, at least you'll have stored previous results and you'll know at which point it crashed (so you can rework that single example by hand and see what went wrong).

Another possibility would be to enclose the inside of your loop in a tryCatch in order to skip the cases where it throws an error and continue regardless.

Here is your reworked code. I have not run it.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
results <- list()
for (i=1:nrow(allData)) {

  Sys.sleep(1)

  try({
  url=paste("http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=",
            as.character(allData$url[i]),
            "&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0#preparse_warnings",
           sep="")
  w = getURL(url,httpheader = c('User-Agent' = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"))

  doc <- htmlTreeParse(w, getDTD = F)
  r=xmlRoot(doc)
  text=r[["body"]][[2]][[4]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
  errors=strsplit(toString.XMLNode(text),' ')[[1]][1]
  warnings=strsplit(toString.XMLNode(text),' ')[[1]][3]
  results[[i]] <- c(as.numeric(errors),as.numeric(warnings))
  })
}

Results <- do.call("rbind", results)
```